# How to add and subtract numbers and indexes for automatically counting list items?

Tags: itemize

What is the easy way of adding and subtracting numbers so that the number of list items can be counted?

For example, the following list contains three items

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{5}
  \item No. 1
  \item No. 2
  \item No. 3
  \label{lst:num}
\end{enumerate}
```

However, the `\ref{lst:num}` would be equal to "8" and therefore it does not correspond to the total number of items.

Comment: Would you please add some more context, in order to understand why you want such a count?

Comment: If you have several enumerate environments in your document, and want to compute some total prior to presenting all the lists then this type of approach where records are counted automatically is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

With `\setcounter{enumi}{5}` you set the counter to `5`, so naturally the last reference will not give the total number of items, but rather *number of items + initial enumi counter value*

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{5}
  \item A No. 1
  \item A No. 2
  \item A No. 3
  \label{lst:num:a}
\end{enumerate}
```

One solution would be not to set the counter to `5` but set it to `0` (that is done automatically), the label of the last item is than equal to the total number of items.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{5}
  \item B No. 1
  \item B No. 2
  \item B No. 3
  \label{lst:num:b}
\end{enumerate}
```

If you want to set the counter to a non-zero value, but still calculate the number of items, the package `refcount` could help you.
As @egreg pointed out, this works only for the first level of the `enumeration` environment.

Put this in your preamble

```
\newcommand{\listlength}[2]{% use: \listlength{label-of-first-item}{label-of-last-item}
  \the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#2}-\getrefnumber{#1}+1\relax   
}
```

and this in your actual document

```
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{5}
  \item C No. 1 \label{lst:num:C:o}
  \item C No. 2
  \item C No. 3 \label{lst:num:C:l}
\end{enumerate} 
Number of items is: \listlength{lst:num:C:o}{lst:num:C:l}.
```

Comment: This won't work for second level `enumerate` environments, because the counter's representation is not numeric.

Comment: That's unfortunate, is there an easy way to also get it running with other levels and different counter representations?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{bbb}\setcounter{bbb}{10}\addtocounterref{bbb}{lst:numEND2}
(\thebbb)
\newcounter{aaa}\setcounter{aaa}{9}\addtocounterref{aaa}{lst:numSTART2}
(\theaaa)
\addtocounter{bbb}{-\value{aaa}}

The list below contains \thebbb  items.

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{5}
\item No. 1
\label{lst:numSTART2}
\item No. 2
\item No. 3
\label{lst:numEND2}
\end{enumerate}
```